# How can I increase my monks maximum spirit?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The base spirit maximum of 150 is pretty low if you actually want to use those spirit-consuming skills frequently. It can happen easily that you don't have enough left when you're trying to use the more expensive skills for 50 or 75 spirit.

The only way to increase the maximum spirit I've found so far is the "Exalted Soul" passive skill, which increases it by 100.

Are there any other ways of increasing the maximum amount of spirit for a monk?

Comment: Alternately, there are runes that decrease the cost for a few skills.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking the wrong question here. Spirit is a fixed pool, the only way to increase the size of it is, as you mentioned, Exalted Soul. This is *meant to be a bottleneck*. The point isn't to be walking around with a full spirit pool to be drained, but rather to *build up* to using a Spirit based skill through the use of various generators. Thus, the solution, if you want to use more of them, is not to increase your maximum spirit, but rather, to *increase the efficiency of your spirit generation and usage*.

And for that, you have *tons* of options. First off, every Spirit Generator has a rune option to increase the Spirit it generates. Most abilities that cost Spirit have options to reduce their cost. Some, like **Exploding Palm** even have runes that make them near to self-sustaining under the right circumstances

Answer (score 3):

Exalted Soul is the only way to increase your maximum spirit.  There are no other skills or  any item affixes that increase spirit.

However there are a number of runes, especially on primary skills, that increase the amount of spirit regenerated by use of the skill(s).  If you're having spirit issues you might want to look into using some of those.

Answer (score 2):

Or as an option, if you'd like. Instead of stacking in dex, try to look for armor or weapons with increased spirit regeneration. That way, when you use an ability with a spirit cost of 75, by the time you hit once with your primary spirit generation ability, the regeneration on your armor etc. will boost that. Thus spirit is viable faster, that paired with the runes on all abilities, then you should be more than good to go.